# Reading file descriptors

Tags: shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

Content of a file named `file`

```
testing 1
testing 2
```

Command tested

```
exec 3<> ./tmp
cat file 1>&3 3>&1
```

Outputs nothing. Why?

I read my command as

`cat` content in `file`, then read `STDOUT` and give it to file descriptor `3` and then take the content from file descriptor `3` and give it's content to `STDOUT`

Am I reading my command wrong ?

How shall I read my command in order to understand it better and get the output of `file`

---

After understanding your answer Stéphane, I tried the following commands

```
cat file 1>&3 3> ofile
```

which didn't write the contents of fd 3 (which gets it's content from fd 1 i.e STDOUT) to `ofile`

but the I tried the following command

```
cat file 1>&3 && cat <3
```

which printed the content of fd 3 to the STDOUT.

Why didn't fd 3 write to `ofile` when fd 3 has the content of fd 1 ?

---

Stéphane, the command Jesse_b mentioned in the comments below i.e

```
cat file 3> ofile 1>&3
```

works and does write the content of `file` to `ofile` but the command

```
cat file 1>&3 3> ofile
```

as I mentioned earlier fails to write to `ofile`.

How did the placement of `1>&3` at the end and at the beginning of `3> ofile` affect the output of these two commands ?

Comment: I don't think that is how any of this works.  If you would like your command to read the contents of `file` to `STDOUT` you can execute this command: `cat file` If you want to redirect `STDOUT` to something else you can do `cat file >` or `cat file 1>`

Comment: When you do `1>&3` you aren't saying "redirect 1 to 3" you are saying "redirect 1 and 3"

Comment: Try `cat file 3> ofile 1>&3` also I don't think your second command is actually working.  I think it's executing: `cat file` and throwing away `1>&3 && cat <3`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it works but I know if you want to throw away all output you put it at the end like this: `command > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmd x>&y` says: "redirect fd x to whatever resource fd y is redirected to"

So in:

```
cat 1>&3 3>&1
```

You're saying that `cat`'s fd 1 (stdout) should go to the same resource as open on fd 3, that is `./tmp` open in read+write mode; and then fd 3 to the same resource as open on fd 1, which you've just made to be `./tmp`.

So `cat` will be started with both its fds 1 and 3 redirected to `./tmp`. `cat` doesn't do anything with its fd 3, you can redirect `cat`'s fd 3 to anything you like, it will have no effect.

However it does write the content of `file` to its fd 1, so you'll find the content of `file` written at the start of `./tmp`.

`cat file` writes the content of `file` only once and only to one fd. If you want something that write the content of `file` twice to two different fds, you'd want `tee` instead:

In

```
< file tee ./tmp
```

`tee` would write what it reads from its fd 0 (here redirected to `file` open in read-only mode) to both `./tmp` (open in write only mode with truncate) and its fd 1 (stdout).

While it's possible to tell `tee` to open `./tmp` in *append* mode with `-a`, you can't tell it to open `./tmp` in read+write mode without truncation like `3<>` does.

For that, you'd need:

```
< file tee /dev/fd/3 3<> ./tmp
```

which would work except on Linux, or resort to using `zsh` and its builtin teeing facility:

```
cat < file 3<> ./tmp >&1 >&3 3>&-
```

With fd 1 being redirected twice, `zsh`, when the `mulltios` option is enabled (on by default), would do an internal tee to forward the output to both destinations  (by running an internal process that reads `cat`'s output and writes it to both destinations).

The temporary use of fd 3 is to work around the the problem that in

```
cat < file >&1 1<> ./tmp
```

zsh would complain with `zsh: file mode mismatch on fd 1` as it supposes you want to *read* from `./tmp`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing why my code didn't work but there's one more problem that I would like you to look into. I have updated my question after reading your answer, please have a look.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, see edit that stresses the fact that `cat` doesn't touch its fd 3, so there's no point trying to make it point to anything.

Comment: There's one more problem, updated my question again, please have a look.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, redirections are processed from left to right. in `cat file 1>&3 3> ofile` you're redirecting fd 1 to whatever resource was open on fd 3 (if there was a `exec 3<> ./tmp` before, then that will be that) and then fd 3 to `ofile`. So we have 1 goes `./tmp`, 3 goes to `ofile`. `cat` doesn't do anything with its fd 3, so all you get is an empty `ofile` because it was open with truncation and nothing was ever written to it.